# Migrate data from one server to another using rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, rsync

I'm moving from one VPS to another, and I figured that the simplest way to transfer data would be `rsync`.

However, the data is owned by a user, `www-data`, which doesn't have ssh privileges, and I'd like it to be owned by the same (named) user on the target machine. Obviously I need all file permissions preserved. I have SSH access via another user with `sudo` privileges on both machines.

Is this possible to do this with rsync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not rsync and chown afterwards? alternatively you can temporarily allow root logins to one of the machiens and run rsync.. if run as root - it'll preserve ownership.

Comment: as a side note, you can do `PermitRootLogin without-password` to enforce a key login, and then `AllowUsers root@ip.add.re.ss` to restrict /which/ hosts you will allow root to login from.